# GET vs POST in SEO

Tags: seo

My web application retrieves a page for every request generated by a form submission. That form submits to the same URL of the page.

Each time the page loads with a different title tag. Does it indicate different pages with the same URL?

How does it affect SEO?  how can I manage this situation?

**Edit**
This question is not purely SEO related no it requires SEO specific reasoning or answers it can be explained also technically how search engine robots work. if it still seems offtopic for moderators I request them to explain why

Comment: for SEO sake, you want visitors to land on specific page. You can achieve it via GET, not POST.

Comment: GET uses query string which are not search engine friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use a rewiter rule to format your URL to a unqiune page if your always loading to the same page google ( or other search engines) will only index that single page.

http://www.seomoz.org/img/upload/anatomy-of-a-url.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm useing codeignitr. hence I think I can make use of IDs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to load the page each time with different title tag you need to append the URL with some uinque text like your GET variable data..

For getting crawled by spiders don't forget to submit your sitemap to search engines with relevant urls..

Comment: Thank you! 
I desired to completely remove form submission method. and the entire request will be in URL. so that I can present each view with unique URL. since I'm using codeignite frame work I can make use of ID. in URL.

Comment: you can definitely access/call your GET urls directly without form submission also..

Comment: but GET produces query string. which are not search engine friendly!

Comment: you have the option of search-engine friendly urls..you can check my website [Lazeez.co.in](http://lazeez.co.in/)..here in a url like `lazeez.co.in/sms/read` refers to a page `read` while the part after `read` is the GET parameter..